# PhoneGap BarcodeScanner - ClassNotFound

Tags: android, cordova, zxing, phonegap-plugins

**UPDATE 2**

I posted an answer that fixes my original problem. See [that for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9541490/398519)

**UPDATE**
FYI for anyone wondering, in the end I found this: http://github.com/commonsguy/zxingdemo/tree/master Exactly what I needed to get it rolling was a simple demo that worked! Also, thanks to Sean for pointing me in the right direction for my googling.

---

I am currently trying to build a simple android app that can scan in a barcode. I have looked through multiple tutorials, tried everything to a T, and re-tried and re-tried. Nothing worked. So now I am going to ask for assistance to see where I went wrong.

To list the tutorials I have followed:

- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner
  Tried this one first.
- http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3
- http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Plus a couple others, but more or less hit the point to the same process. Some key points, when I add the `LibraryProject` to my project as a Library, the app will not compile until I create an `AndroidManifest.xml` I tried using the one found in the LibraryProject and tried creating a bare mininmal one, both would allow to compile, but the app ForceCloses.

When I load up the App and click "Scan" it ForceCloses and in the debug log of LogCat in Eclipse I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.google.com.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk]
```

I have tried googling, found a few issues, but no real clear or solid answers, most just point to the tutorials above. I am not sure if the tutorials are just outdated or I am being stupid and am missing something key. Been working on this for a few days now and am at my wits end.

If you can help I would appreciate it. To avoid answers regarding if I have done X or X, here is what I have done.

When I test the application, I do briefly see it trying to load BarcodeScanner, but right after I see that it ForceCloses. I am not sure what I am missing, but for references I will post the code I currently have setup to test:

AndroidManifest.xml - http://pastebin.com/qq9q0ZU7

Plugins.xml - http://pastebin.com/dZ5eKPSU

index.html - http://pastebin.com/wvht4ken

If I need to post any other items let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so for anyone having this problem, you have two choices. You can use the ScanningViaIntent, as Sean pointed out. It works great, if you need an example look at CommonsGuy. As for the tutorials I posted above to get this working with PhoneGap, my whole problem was, after I imported the `LibraryProject` I did not go back through and add the files. I am not sure if a setting in my Eclipse is bad. But I basically just right clicked on the LibraryProject, went to Import -> File Structure -> Library Project's original project path, and loaded all of it back in there.

There is probably something wrong with my Eclipse setup, but yea. I now have the BarcodeScanner plugin for PhoneGap working!

Comment: Hi I Want to make bar code scanner for my application how can you do this can please explain me.. and also which example you used zxingdemo  or you used phoneGap demo.... zxingdemo is working for me.but how to do with phoneGap demo....how to use of it.. can please tell me...

Answer (score 5):

On Android, it is much much simpler than all this you're trying to do. Throw this out and restart from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Leading me in the right track. I just need to gain more knowledge of Android Development. One way or another I will get er figured out. Thanks again for showing me that. Will credit the 100 points in a couple days.

Comment: FYI for anyone wondering, in the end I found this: https://github.com/commonsguy/zxingdemo/tree/master Exactly what I needed to get it rolling was a simple demo that worked!

Comment: @BradFJacobs: So did you have to create a PhoneGap plugin to get the results back?

Comment: Ranhiru, no I did not. I posted the answer which works http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541490/398519  "But I basically just right clicked on the LibraryProject, went to Import -> File Structure -> Library Project's original project path, and loaded all of it back in there"