# Use BarcodeScanner with Phonegap 5.3.6

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've added the [`PhoneGap Plugin BarcodeScanner`](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) to my phonegap project with

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git
```

And then I wan't to scan a qr-code after I click on a button:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {
    $('#scanButton').click(function () {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function (result) {
                alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

But when I click on the button, I get this javascript error:

```
Cannot read property 'barcodeScanner' of undefined
```

Do I miss something?

I've already tried many solutions from other questions, but none of them works.

e.g. `window.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();`, `window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan`

I use phonegap v5.3.6

Comment: The readme.md on the git repository says that your method of install is unstable: [BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner), maybe try the suggested method: `phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` and see if that works better?

Comment: I already tried it that way, doesn't work either :/

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523278/phonegap-barcodescanner-classnotfound?rq=1) has a working example called out in it, maybe it'll get you going.

Comment: I'm not using eclipse. I want to create a cross-platform app and phonegap should compile it for Android, iOS and WP.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Auroratic? I'm trying to get the plugin to work in PhoneGap 6 but clicking the button doesn't do a thing, not even an error in the PhoneGap server console..

Comment: @Joshua - Pendo no, sadly not :( I moved from phonegap to native applications, which is inconvenient :/

Comment: Too bad. I'm currently testing with Telerik AppBuilder which has 2 barcode scanners tested. Depending on your needs it's a good platform so far. Thanks for your response!

Comment: It looks good, but it's really expensive.